# Stop service and take back up of respected folder items and start service

Tags: powershell, service

I wrote a script which will

1. stop different services of two or more servers (one server containing two services),
2. take a back up of respected folders (folder name starting with Job) to backup folder,
3. copy newest files from staging location to destination folder,
4. start different services in servers.

Looks like I have chosen long procedure to do it. Please suggest if I can modify the script.

```
Function Get-Kettle
{
    $DestinationFolder = "D:\AppCode\Kettle"
    $BackUpFolder = "D:\AppCode\Kettle\BackUp"
    $StagingFolder = "\\server001\e$\Packages\RTO\RTO\ETL"
    $ServerList = @("server222")
    $ServicesList = @("WindowsScheduler","WindowsSchedulerLogon")
    Foreach ($Server in $ServerList)
    {
        $CheckStagingFolder = Get-ChildItem $StagingFolder
        if($CheckStagingFolder.count)
        {
            Write-Host "StagingFolder contains files.. Continue with Deployment"
            if((Test-Path "$DestinationFolder") -and (Test-Path "$BackUpFolder"))
            {
                Write-Host "Taking BackUp"
                Copy-Item "$DestinationFolder" -Destination "$BackUpFolder"
                Write-Host "BackUp is completed"
                Write-Host "Stopping the service WindowsSchedulerLogon"
                Stop-Service $Server.WindowsSchedulerLogon -Force
                Write-Host "WindowsSchedulerLogon service is stopped"
                Write-Host "Stopping the service WindowsScheduler"
                Stop-Service WindowsScheduler -Force
                Write-Host "WindowsScheduler service is stopped"
                Copy-Item "$StagingFolder" -Destination "$DestinationFolder" -Recurse
                Write-Host "Starting the service WindowsSchedulerLogon"
                Start-Service WindowsSchedulerLogon -Force
                Write-Host "WindowsSchedulerLogon service is Started"
                Write-Host "Starting the service WindowsScheduler"
                Start-Service WindowsScheduler -Force
                Write-Host "WindowsScheduler service is started"
                Write-Host "Deployment is completed"
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "No Destination and BackUp Folder..Script Exiting...!"
                Exit;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "StagingFolder does not contains files.. Exiting with Deployment"
            exit;
        }
    }
}
Get-Kettle
```

Comment: Since the question apparently is about improving working code it belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - By any chance could you please share me similar code basis on above it would be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this would be better placed on Code Review but as it's still open here I thought I'd suggest some improvements:

- Add `[cmdletbinding()]` and put your variables at the top in a `Param()` block. Cmdletbinding means you get access to a set of common parameters that allow you to utilise a series of builtin functionality (such as `Write-Verbose` which I will mention later). Putting your variables in a Param block means you can change them by calling them in your Function, just like you do with built-in cmdlets.
- Add `Begin`, `Process` and `End` blocks. I can't see any need to do anything in Begin or End at this point, but the rest of your code can live in Process. This means you could later change this function to support pipeline input if you wanted to.
- Change all your `Write-Host` statements to `Write-Verbose`. [Write-Host is considered harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) because it interferes with automation. Write-Verbose means you can see information messages when you want to but not by default, and those messages to a separate output stream that doesn't then interfere with the output of the function. To see the messages simply do `Get-Kettle -Verbose`. A further benefit of this is that it will also turn on the `-Verbose` messages that are built in to the standard cmdlets you are using (such as `Copy-Item` or `Start-Service`).
- You can should change your last two `Write-Host` statements (in the `else` blocks) to `Write-Warning` messages, these will then always be displayed (regardless of `-verbose` etc.) when you need to inform the user of something but again, do not interfere the default output pipeline.
- You can drop the `Exit` statements as they not really achieving anything.

**Other improvements you might consider include:**

- [Accepting input from the pipeline](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/05/07/tips-on-implementing-pipeline-support/).
- [Parameter sets](http://wragg.io/create-dynamic-powershell-functions-with-parameter-sets/) or validating on your parameters and setting variable types on them (such as `[string]` etc.).
- [Supporting `-confirm` and `-whatif`](http://wragg.io/clean-up-paused-devices-from-prtg-with-powershell/) by adding supportsshouldprocess and putting these around the parts of the script that make changes.

All of these things are features of what is called an Advanced function or Cmdlet. If you haven't read it, take a look at [Learn PowerShell Toolmaking in a Month of Lunches](https://www.manning.com/books/learn-powershell-toolmaking-in-a-month-of-lunches) as it covers these topics and a lot more.

Here's a copy of your code with the first set of improvements I suggested implemented:

```
Function Get-Kettle
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        $DestinationFolder = "D:\AppCode\Kettle",
        $BackUpFolder = "D:\AppCode\Kettle\BackUp",
        $StagingFolder = "\\server001\e$\Packages\RTO\RTO\ETL",
        $ServerList = @("server222"),
        $ServicesList = @("WindowsScheduler","WindowsSchedulerLogon")
    )
    Begin {}
    Process {
        Foreach ($Server in $ServerList)
        {
            $CheckStagingFolder = Get-ChildItem $StagingFolder
            if($CheckStagingFolder.count)
            {
                Write-Verbose "StagingFolder contains files.. Continue with Deployment"
                if((Test-Path "$DestinationFolder") -and (Test-Path "$BackUpFolder"))
                {
                    Write-Verbose "Taking BackUp"
                    Copy-Item "$DestinationFolder" -Destination "$BackUpFolder"
                    Write-Verbose "BackUp is completed"
                    Write-Verbose "Stopping the service WindowsSchedulerLogon"
                    Stop-Service $Server.WindowsSchedulerLogon -Force
                    Write-Verbose "WindowsSchedulerLogon service is stopped"
                    Write-Verbose "Stopping the service WindowsScheduler"
                    Stop-Service WindowsScheduler -Force
                    Write-Verbose "WindowsScheduler service is stopped"
                    Copy-Item "$StagingFolder" -Destination "$DestinationFolder" -Recurse
                    Write-Verbose "Starting the service WindowsSchedulerLogon"
                    Start-Service WindowsSchedulerLogon -Force
                    Write-Verbose "WindowsSchedulerLogon service is Started"
                    Write-Verbose "Starting the service WindowsScheduler"
                    Start-Service WindowsScheduler -Force
                    Write-Verbose "WindowsScheduler service is started"
                    Write-Verbose "Deployment is completed"
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Warning "No Destination and BackUp Folder..Script Exiting...!"
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Warning "StagingFolder does not contains files.. Exiting with Deployment"
            }
        }
    }
    End {}
}

Get-Kettle -Verbose
```